# creating json object with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am trying to create a json object from variables that I am getting in a form.

```
var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
var lastName  = $('#lastName').val();
var phone     = $('#phoneNumber').val();
var address   = $('#address').val();
```

So far I have the code below but it will not validate or work. Im new to this, please help!
Changing var to this:

```
var jsonObject = 
                {
                 firstName: firstName, 
                 lastName: lastName,
                 phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
                 address:address
                }
```

in JSONlint i am getting this error:

> Parse error on line 1:
>   varjsonObject={
>   ^
>   Expecting '{', '['

Comment: Are you sure you want to create **JSON** and not rather a JS object? Also, what parts of the object are supposed to be variables? How is the first part connected to the second part? If you really want to convert `formObject` to JSON, then you are out of luck, since you cannot convert jQuery objects to JSON (and you are missing `$` in `"firstName": ('#firstName')`). Please be specific about the result you want to get, right now it's a bit confusing since it seems you are struggling with the right terminology.

Comment: You might find it helpful to read more about object in the MDN JavaScript Guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Comment: the result I want is a json object that i can send using ajax.

Comment: JSON objects don't exist (http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Either you want actually a JS object and set it as `data: ...` in the `$.ajax` configuration. Or you want to convert the object to JSON and send a string containing JSON to the server. The reason why you get the error in JSONlint is that you are inputting JavaScript (`var jsonObject = ..`), and not JSON. If you input the output of `JSON.stringify(jsonObject)` instead, it will probably validate. I really recommend you to take the time to learn what exactly JSON is, compared to JS object literals.

Comment: `var jsonObject = {...}` is valid JavaScript, ***but not valid JSON***!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

if you need double quoted JSON use `JSON.stringify( object)`

```
var $items = $('#firstName, #lastName,#phoneNumber,#address ')
var obj = {}
$items.each(function() {
    obj[this.id] = $(this).val();
})

var json= JSON.stringify( obj);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vANKa/1

Answer (score 15):

It's called on **Object Literal**

I'm not sure what you want your structure to be, but according to what you have above,  where you put the values in variables try this.

```
var formObject =  {"formObject": [
                {"firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName},
                {"phoneNumber": phone},
                {"address": address},
                ]}
```

Although this seems to make more sense (Why do you have an array in the above literal?):

```
var formObject = {
   firstName: firstName
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this to see how you can create a object from strings.

```
var firstName = "xx";
var lastName  = "xy";
var phone     = "xz";
var adress    = "x1";
var obj = {"firstName":firstName, "lastName":lastName, "phone":phone, "address":adress};
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're referencing a DOM element when doing something like `$('#lastName')`.  That's an element with `id` attribute "lastName".  Why do that?  You want to reference the value stored in a local variable, completely unrelated.  Try this (assuming the assignment to `formObject` is in the same scope as the variable declarations) -

```
var formObject = {
    formObject: [
        {
            firstName:firstName,  // no need to quote variable names
            lastName:lastName
        },
        {
            phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
            address:address
        }
    ]
};
```

This seems very odd though: you're creating an object "formObject" that contains a member called "formObject" that contains an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
var formValues = {
    firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
    lastName: $('#lastName').val(),
    phone: $('#phoneNumber').val(),
    address: $('#address').val()
};
```

Note this will contain the values of the elements **at the point in time the object literal was interpreted**, not when the properties of the object are accessed. You'd need to write a getter for that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is the way i used variables correct in my updated code?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, it is correct. However, JSLint will provide you with no meaningful information because you have a **javascript object**, not JSON.