# Creating a variable name of a property in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm running this code.

```javascript
var output = {"records": []};
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  output.records[i] = { propertyName : data[i][propertyName] }
```

I expected the output to be on the following form.

```
{ "cat" : "mjau" }
{ "dog" : "woff" }
```

Instead, I get to my surprise this.

```
{ "propertyName" : "mjau" }
{ "propertyName" : "woff" }
```

How can I get variable *propertyName*?

I'm trying to create a parser that will create a number of records that are all *cat* but, when called from an other place, the records should have *dog* property instead. I wish to avoid creating two different code pieces for that.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979335/creating-json-object-with-variables), which **I suspect** contains the answer to my issue. However, due to ignorance, I don't get it.

Comment: where do you put those cat n dog?? i mean where do you hold those properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating json object with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979335/creating-json-object-with-variables)

Comment: @jbabey Congrats! I mentioned in my question that I found **that exact question**. I also explained that due to lack of skills, I don't understand it. What's the point of mentioning it **again**? Besides, the answers I got here are very clear and actually helpful, so **exact** duplicate it is not. :)

Comment: @BhushanFirake I'm not sure what you mean. Those are just some property names that I'll be working with.

Answer (score 3):

Keys in object literals won't be evaluated in JavaScript. So, you need to create an empty object (`{}`) and then assign the key dynamically:

```
output.records[i] = {};
output.records[i][propertyName] = data[i][propertyName]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {b:'c'}
```

is just like

```
var a = {};
a['b'] = 'c';
```

What you want is

```
a[b] = c
```

that is

```
output.records[i] = {};
output.records[i][propertyName] = data[i][propertyName];
```

You have in this MDN document : [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 0):

In `{ propertyName : data[i][propertyName] }` the property name part should be constant string. It you pass a variable it wont fetch its value.

What you have to do is

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var a = {};
  a[propertyName] = data[i][propertyName];
  output.records.push(a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
'"' + propertyName + '"' : ...
```

Comment: I notice that your approach is different from most of the others. Is it the same thing expressed with an other syntax or is it a different method? If so, which is preferable in this case?

Comment: No. I misunderstood. All I'm doing in the above is wrapping the string in quotes. OP would probably get something like ""propertyName"".